# WebStorm integrated terminal incorrectly displays font glyphs

Tags: webstorm, glyphicons

I use zsh with OSX and have custom glyphs added to my fonts. WebStorm's integrated terminal is the only application that seems to squish the glyphs too close, as shown in the attached screenshot. iTerm, Terminal and VS Code all display the glyphs correctly.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set same font for Webstorm's console as you use for iTerm and Terminal. Go to "Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Font", set Primary font (I use Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline with size 14) and a fallback Secondary font (Menlo in my case). Enable ligatures as well.

[Here is the screenshot of my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zikL.png)

Result is not perfect, but better as on your screenshot.